# Buttons change each other

Tags: javascript

Good evening!

I have a problem with conversion html code into new one, then go back by pressing new created button to the old one.

Problem is that when you press the button that one will convert into new one, but when I press again (new created code) it is not going back to the old one even when created code is correct (I mean id's).

There is my HTML code:

```
<div id="me_div">
    <a href="#" id= "me" class="btn btn-success">me</a>
</div>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#me').click(function() {
        alert("Here I am!");
        $("#me_div").html('<a href="#" id= "noob" class="btn btn-danger">noob</a>');
        document.getElementById("me_div").setAttribute("id", "noob_div");
    });

    $('#noob').click(function() {
        alert("Im noob with JS.");
        $("#noob_div").html('<a href="#" id= "me" class="btn btn-success">me</a>');
        document.getElementById("noob_div").setAttribute("id", "me_div");
    });
});
```

Comment: Your `click` listeners are attached to SPECIFIC buttons. When you replace their HTML you lose the event listeners. You need to re-attach the event listeners, but better yet rethink the process. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom Rees answer will fix your problem, but consider rethinking your solution. Don't destroy and create new HTML every time a button is clicked and re-assign IDs! Why not show/hide?

http://jsfiddle.net/agmr2ytd/

```
$(function() {
    $('#me').click(function() {
        alert("Here I am!");
        $("#me_div").hide();
        $("#noob_div").show();
    });

    $('#noob').click(function() {
        alert("Here I am!");
        $("#noob_div").hide();
        $("#me_div").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you think that is not fast enough? I'm writing a favorite content ajax code.

Comment: It's faster to show/hide then to regenerate HTML and rebind listeners.

Comment: I think that would be a problem due to my ajax php file, when you press favorite while it is hidden (by editing HTML code like google dev app) my database will be suprised of the POST data.

Comment: You can edit the html using dev tools. In fact you can send the ajax post request directly from the console. Handle the false request in your php file. You can't control the client to that extent.

Comment: I've done that already, I made an secure php file, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When that function executes, there is no `#noob` to bind to. You need to run the bind code every time the DOM is altered, eg.:

```
$(function() {
    window.bindToMe = function() {
        $('#me').click(function() {
            alert("Here I am!");
            $("#me_div").html('<a href="#" id= "noob" class="btn btn-danger">noob</a>');
            document.getElementById("me_div").setAttribute("id", "noob_div");
            bindToNoob();
        });
    }

    window.bindToNoob = function() {
        $('#noob').click(function() {
            alert("Im noob with JS.");
            $("#noob_div").html('<a href="#" id= "me" class="btn btn-success">me</a>');
            document.getElementById("noob_div").setAttribute("id", "me_div");
            bindToMe();
        });
    }

    bindToMe();
});
```